# How to get current focused menu item

Tags: android, focus, android-navigation

I have a searchview and at some point of execution I would like to get the current focussed view from the searchview.I am trying to achieve this by using api `Activity.getCurrentfocus() or getWindow.getDecorView.FindFocus(`). But both of the api is *returning null* **although searchview is focused**.

*My questions is how to get the current focused view from a options menu/ searchview* ?

Answer (score -1):

**Documentation:**

> [`View getCurrentFocus()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getCurrentFocus())
>
> Return the view in this Window that currently has focus, **or null if
>   there are none**. Note that this does not look in any containing Window.

You can debug it by calling `getCurrentFocus()` within `onQueryTextSubmit`

```
   @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        // Get the focus of the SearchView
        View current = getCurrentFocus();
        if (current != null)
           // Has focus
        else
          // No focus

        return false;
    }
```